# FlowLayoutPanel glitch with a lot of children

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having trouble with FlowLayoutPanel and child controls rendering. If I add 300+ child controls, panel stops to render them at some point. Last displayed item has sort of overlap and all other child controls are missing. Thanks.

[image: FlowLayoutPanel glitch]

Comment: argghhh! rethink your design..!!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like FlowLayoutPanel does not support lot of controls. The way I fixed it was creating new user control that includes FlowLayoutPanel and Vertical scroll bar. Panel holds 100 controls at one time and logic handles v scroll bar position, add or remove controls to panel.

This way allows to handle 4000+ child controls.

Comment: 4000+ controls?  Yeah, you are going to have to rethink this design.  Controls are an expensive resource in WinForms.