# How to add 1000+ Dynamic controls without crashing program

Tags: c#, dynamic, controls

Since it was explained to me that I asked an XY Question, let me rephrase it.

I am starting a remote process on what could be anywhere from 1 to 1000 clients or more, and I want a form/panel/listview (doesn't matter) that will show me their individual progress in one location.

Short of creating a seperate ProgressBar for each one, which may cause crashes, or performance issues, what would be the best way to address this?

Currently, I have found that if I place the progressbars in a listview, it won't crash when it creates hundreds, or even 1000 of them, but performance is slow, for obvious reasons.

I have other solutions that I can use, but I am looking for what might be the best way get what I want, without taxing the system.

The best one I thought of, would involve me using DirectX to create progressbar objects that I would calculate and then render to the display as one image, like you would with 1000's of objects in a video game.

I am just curious if there is a real good way to do this using the built in components, without resorting to DirectX.

I left the old text here for reference.

PREVIOUS QUESTION:
I am trying to add a control, in this case, a Label to a panel for each item selected from a ListView.

If I select more than 120 or so Items, it crashes my program. So I tested a simple loop adding a label and it also crashes the program.

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'Error creating window handle.'

Apparently I run out of handles between 100-200 labels. It seems if I add them slowly, one at a time by selecting them in the list with the control key, I don't have this problem.

It works fine with less than that amount, although it's slow to repaint.

Is there a way to add 1000 or more controls dynamically without crashing the program? Or do I have to resort to DirectX and create my own graphics to accomplish this?

EDIT (per request from the community):

A little more background on what I'm attempting to accomplish.

I have a list of client workstations, and when I select one, or a group of them, or all of them from the list, I want a tile to appear for each one, in a panel, that has the workstation name and a progressbar for an action being performed.

```
    private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Controls.Clear();

        int cNumber = listView1.SelectedItems.Count;
        int MaxColumns = panel1.Width / 100;
        int Row = 0;

        Label[] lb = new Label[cNumber];

        for (int i = 0; i < cNumber; i++)
        {
            // Initialize one variable 

            lb[i] = new Label();
            // Set location
            if (i - (MaxColumns * Row) >= MaxColumns) Row++;
            lb[i].Location = new Point((i - (MaxColumns * Row)) * 105, Row * 110);


            lb[i].Text = i.ToString();
            // Add to the panel
            panel1.Controls.Add(lb[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need 1000 controls? What does the application do?

Comment: `it crashes my program.` What exact exception is thrown, from what line?

Comment: Any program that needs 1000+ controls is almost certainly in serious need of a redesign...

Comment: Use better hardware.

Comment: @SeM: It wouldn't matter, it's likely an OS limitation like too many GDI objects or something like that

Comment: Have you considered using a second ItemsControl instead of manually creating Labels like crazy?

Comment: @musefan well, it will be clearer, if OP will describe more about what he means under _"crash"_.

Comment: Also the fact that it's inside a selectedindexchanged event is probably causing some issues.

Comment: What exactly is it you want to use all these labels for anyway? If you provide a little more background information, perhaps someone can provide you with a better solution?

Comment: I think a better question is _how to ensure my app does not give my users a headache?_

Comment: @musefan _"...it's likely an OS limitation like too many GDI objects"_ - the limit per Windows session is anywhere between [16,384 and 65,536](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724291(v=vs.85).aspx) so `1000` isn't that high.  I do agree though that 1000 per window would be a UX headache.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
Always __TAG__ your question correctly!

Comment: There is a simple solution short of DirectX : TextRederer.DrawText the label texts!

Comment: thanks KJartan - 

A little more background on what I'm attempting to accomplish. 

I have a list of client workstations, and when I select one, or a group of them, or all of them from the list, I want a tile to appear for each one, in a panel, that has the workstation name and a progressbar for an action being performed.

I simplified it to just a label for testing.

Comment: [virtualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22925465/flowlayoutpanel-glitch-with-lot-of-child)

Comment: Unless you have a 100k display you won't be able to display them all at once. Displaying a reasonable amount with paging-scrolling is the obvious solution, maybe using a flowlayoutpanel, unless you want to/can switch to wpf. - Or draw each state bitmap whenever a progressbars changes. - As I commented below: You can easily create 10k+ controls as long as they are not displayed. Put them in  a List and display only a screen full..

Comment: The component that hasn't been mentioned clearly enough is the poor User. No matter how many controls your system can handle, a human being drops out after 5. It is the task of software to turn heaps of data into _information_. Information is defined by the user.

Comment: @bommelding, your comment is not helpful. I know you think that you are being clever, but if it doesn't add to the solution, perhaps it's best not to comment.

Comment: @JeffS - You should make sure you know what a X/Y question is. Because you asked one.

Comment: I resolved the issue. It wasn't a resource limit that was being hit. This can be closed.

Comment: by the way, thanks Henk Holterman, I found that helpful. I googled XY problem.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this is an intresting question, that bother me too some time ago (how many controls I can add to single form?). So this is a good reason to check. I have create a new WinForms project and modify form code to this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            Controls.Add(new Label { Text = $"{i}" });
    }
}
```

At run-time (after about 1-minute freeze) app throw a `Win32Exception` with **NativeErrorCode** 1158. As you can see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681383(v=vs.85).aspx), this is **ERROR_NO_MORE_USER_HANDLES**. A quick googling for this error point me to [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms725486(v=vs.85).aspx).

There you can find, that there is "theoretical limit" of 65536 User objects per session.

> However, the maximum number of user handles that can be opened per session is usually lower, since it is affected by available memory. There is also a default per-process limit of user handles.

And if you look for **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\USERProcessHandleQuota** in registry, you will find actual limit of user handles. For my Win7 it is 10000.

*--- **Update** ---*

There is a [GetGuiResources function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms683192(v=vs.85).aspx) that can help us to count current handles usage. Like this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern uint GetGuiResources(IntPtr hProcess, uint uiFlags);
```

If `uiFlags` is 0 (**GR_GDIOBJECTS**) it will return GDI objects count, and if 1 (**GR_USEROBJECTS**) it will return User objects count.

I add a button, that on click adds 1000 labels to parent form, and a timer, that on tick count GDI and User objects count and set result to window title.

So, right after startup, there was **36** GDI objects and **35** User objects. And on each button click I have exactly **1000** additional user objects and **0** additional GDI object. After some clicks we hit User object limit (10 000), but GDI objects count is still 36.

As a result, I can say, that I can have maximum of **~9970** controls on a form with default Windows 7 setup:)

Comment: Another _[useful link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724291(v=vs.85).aspx)_.

Comment: It was set to `10.000` (windows 10) for me also, but I've tested and app will crash if number bigger than `9976`.

Comment: @User453465436754 - this is not a GDI limit in this case, I will edit my answer to prove this

Comment: @SeM - this is because even an empty winforms application already own ~30 user handles

Comment: That's ok, I was agreeing with you and just providing an additional helpful link. I already +1 you :)

Comment: Just want to add that creating the Labels is no issue at all. Only adding them __visibly__ to a __visible__ Controls collection runs into the problems.

Comment: @User453465436754, thanks, but I can't stop now:)

Comment: @Taw, I add them to form's `Controls`, so they are visible. They appear at top left corner of form.

Comment: Of course. Just wanted to add this observation. If they are invisble or if they are added to an invisible container all seems fine. That is until the container is shown. I'm working on a path editor and am considering to have all its points to be movable labels but only show some of them at a time, so I can't stop now either :-)

Comment: @musefan, well, he now knows, that there is 2 OS limits, that his application probably hit. He now knows, where in system registry he can extend this limits. He now knows, that there is a `GetGuiResources` function, that can help him to find exactly which. He now knows, that this is most likely not a hardware issue. And, I hope, he now knows, that adding 1000 controls to form - is terrable idea and there should be a redesign, not refactoring.

Comment: @musefan, I'm sure, that solution is provided:\ In short it is: "You must not add this much controls to your form, OS doesn't allow it (for a good reason). You should redesign your application."

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution came to me over lunch.

Just load what the panel can display, Let's say 30 clients, and instead of scrolling, have and up/down scroll button that just changes the client name text and progressbar value to match the next group of 30 clients up or down the list.

Don't know why I didn't think to do it that way before. Probably because scrolling through a list of 1000 clients would take too long, but I can add filters and search feature I suppose.

The real issue was with the SelectedIndexChanged function, as soon as I changed the trigger to an actual button click, it would work flawlessly and I tested with 1000 progressbars, which it could add in about 5 seconds.

I still concede that this is only one possible method of several that I've proposed, but haven't heard any better ways to achieve what I'm looking to do, other than TaW mentioned something similar to paging then with scrolling like I did above.